What is the expected size of primes sampled uniformly at random from the set of first $2^n$ primes?
Suppose, $\mathbb{P}_n$ denotes the set of first $2^n$ primes and $p\xleftarrow{\$}\mathbb{P}_n$ denotes the sampling of a prime $p$ from the set $\mathbb{P}_n$ uniformly at random. I want to find the expectation of $\log_2{p}$. I have proceeded upto this following point, but unable to simplify further.
The prime number theorem (PNT) states that the number of primes upto an integer $m$ is $\approx m/\log{m}$. Therefore, $$\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}^+\text{ and }\forall p\in\mathbb{P}_k,\text{ we have}\log{p}> k+\log{k},$$ and $$\Pr[p\in\mathbb{P}_k\mid p\xleftarrow{\$}\mathbb{P}_n]=\frac{|\mathbb{P}_k|}{|\mathbb{P}_n|}=\frac{2^k}{2^n}.$$
So, the expectation is,
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[\log{p}\mid p\xleftarrow{\$}\mathbb{P}_n] &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\log{p}\mid p\in\mathbb{P}_k]\times \Pr[p\in\mathbb{P}_k\mid p\xleftarrow{\$}\mathbb{P}_n]\\
&>\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+\log{k})\cdot\frac{2^k}{2^n}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+\log{k})\cdot2^k\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot2^k+\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log{k}\cdot2^k\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot2^k+\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log{k}\cdot2^k\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\times [(n-1)2^{n+1}+2] +\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log{k}\cdot2^k\\
&>2(n-1) +\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log{k}\cdot2^k\\
\end{split}
Is it the correct direction? If yes, how to simplify the second sum further? I understand that,
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log{k}\cdot2^k
&>\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\times (2^{n+1}-1) \\
&\approx 2.\\
\end{split}
But, this is just an approximation.

Let $x$ be the $2^n$th prime. Then the expectation in question is precisely
$$
\frac1{2^n} \sum_{p\le x} \log_2 p = \frac1{2^n\log 2} \sum_{p\le x} \log p.
$$
By the prime number theorem, the latter sum (usually denoted $\theta(x)$) is asymptotic to $x$, and thus the expectation is
$$
\sim \frac1{2^n\log 2} x \sim \frac1{2^n\log 2} 2^n\log(2^n) = n.
$$
This is reasonably consistent with numerical experimentation.

Thank you @Greg Martin. I think $\theta(x)$ is called the Chebyshev function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function
